# How to publish ASP.NET Core app to ftp server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

Visual Studio publish only supports importing web deploy.

Is there a workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual Studio publishing profiles supports pure FTP as a target. It does not support SFTP however.

These are the options you should see:

- Web Deploy
- Web Deploy Package
- FTP (does not support SFTP unfortunately)
- File System (UNC or local path)

**Update since noted ASP.NET 5**

With the details that the project is ASP.NET 5 / vNext, at this time, FTP and Web Deploy are not supported yet in the UI of Visual Studio. There's a blog out there following these steps to import an FTP profile:

1. Open notepad and create a publishing profile to save to your file system.

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <publishData>
     <publishProfile profileName="FTP" publishMethod="FTP" publishUrl="ftp://ftpaddress" userName="username" userPWD="password" destinationAppUrl="http://wwwaddress" />
   </publishData>
2. Select "Import" from the publish targets and import the publishing profile.

Link to Blog: http://blog.discountasp.net/publishing-an-asp-net-5-vnext-application/

Comment: The site i want to publish to is:  ftp.Smarterasp.net

Comment: That is pure FTP over port 21, so that should not be a problem. Depending on you VS version, you select "custom" publishing target, then change "Web Deploy" (default dropdown under Connection) to "FTP", then enter your FTP connection details there. You'll need the hostname (ftp.Smarterasp.net), username/password, and path.

Comment: @Gorel - Ah, I see in your edit to the post you are using vNext/.NET 5, which the UI doesn't support FTP yet as it's still in 'preview'. Check out this blog on how to import an FTP profile into vNext projects: http://blog.discountasp.net/publishing-an-asp-net-5-vnext-application/

Comment: When I try this, I get an alert box showing `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: It works, but it upload a .exe, a .dll, a couple of .json and other files, but no index.html or index.php, can't access anything from browser (error 403). Is a dedicated server needed to run ASP.NET Core web apps?

Comment: Many people run lots of apps on the same server, but you do have to configure them differently since .NET Core. For instance in Windows with IIS, you need to have the IIS hosting bundle and setup IIS app pool correctly. Here's a quick guide from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio