# Is it possible to publish a .NET Core console application over FTP in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: ftp, visual-studio-2019

My question is **nearly** identical to this [How to publish ASP.NET Core app to ftp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672930/how-to-publish-asp-net-core-app-to-ftp-server) with the exception my question is .NET (where as the linked question is for ASP.NET).

However, I think I can follow the instructions on that link. I click Publish, and choose Import Profile and I import the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<publishData> 
    <publishProfile profileName="FTP" publishMethod="FTP" publishUrl="ftp://ftp.domain.co.uk/project/" userName="user" userPWD="***" destinationAppUrl="http://www.domain.co.uk/Software/project/" />
</publishData>
```

When I do this and click I finish, I see

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

[image]

This used to be very simple with .net framework and click once.

Is it possible to publish a .NET Core console application over FTP in Visual Studio 2019?